# Java Scanner is not working while reading a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
public class Test {

    static private Scanner x;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try {
            x=new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\scoda\\workspace\\Nikhil\\src\\chinese.txt"));
            x.useDelimiter(" ");
            while(x.hasNext())  
            {

                String a=x.next();
                String b=x.next();              
                String c=x.next();
                System.out.println(a+b+c);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My input file is

```
12 karthik kk
23 gg gg
```

Expected output:

```
12karthikkk
23gggg
```

Actual output:

```
12karthikkk
23
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
```

I am trying to debug the issue from a long time .
Help is appreciated.

Comment: personally I would read the whole line and then split on `" "`

Comment: Have you tried printing a, b, and c inside the loop?

Comment: I tried reading the whole line i dint work for me

Comment: I tried printing a,b,c inside loop it prints fine but at the end it shows the exception

Comment: Is it possible that the scanner detects that there is something beyond the last "gg", for example a newline? That would mean that String = x.next() would cause the exception. Would you place a counter before the loop and see whether the exception occurs at iteration 4? (start at 1, print before the Scanner#next() calls.) EDIT: basically what shmosel says.

Answer (score 4):

Because you changed the delimiter to space, the newline isn't counted as a separator, and there are actually only 5 tokens in your string:

1. 12
2. karthik
3. kk

   23
4. gg
5. gg

Your code is throwing an exception on the second call to `String c=x.next();`, because there is no sixth token. If you remove the `x.useDelimiter(" ");` statement, it will use the [default whitespace delimiter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#default-delimiter), which will split on your newline as well, resulting in 6 tokens.

Comment: Thanks a lot , Understood my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(10);
        try
        {
            x = new Scanner(new File("D:\\test1.txt"));
            x.useDelimiter(" ");

            while (x.hasNext())
            {

                String a = x.next();
                buffer.append(a);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());
    }
```